# Cannot access custom HTTP headers within flask on production environment (NGINX + Gunicorn3)

Tags: python, nginx, flask, gunicorn

As the title says I am trying to access a custom header via flask

```
@app.route("/test", methods=['POST'])
def ticket():
  odn_key = request.headers.get('HTTP_ODN_KEY')
  return odn_key
```

This works within my test environment (IDE) but I cannot seem to access those headers through gunicorn / flask.

I've read something about the header not being able to have underscores and that it replaces all hyphens with underscores. My test request (via postman) header is odn-key: 12345

Any help is appreciated!

Thanks,
JH

Comment: did you try to just print all available headers from `request` and find the needed one?

Comment: It seems likely to me that something you have proxying the request (nginx?) isn't forwarding that header. If the header were passed, you would see it.

Comment: please check replacing underscore with hyphen, HTTP_ODN_KEY to HTTP-ODN-KEY

For instance Nginx with the default configuration will ignore headers with underscore in the name (see http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#underscores_in_headers and http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#ignore_invalid_headers documentation).